# Yii2: Where to store uploaded files?

Tags: php, yii2

**Story:**
User should upload some private files to the server. And he should have access to that files, for read(like viewing images or pdf files). I placed them not in web root, so there is no direct link to them. But after the first request, when the server publish them for authenticated user, it becomes available for all others by web/assets/* links.

**Question:**

*Is there a way to clear assets with every request? Or is there a better way to publish private files only for owners?*

Comment: You may save the files in a location that is accessible only through a script and files can be served using a script.

Comment: You can put one php file in your upload folder.In which you can write script for authenticate and serve the user.

Comment: @khaleel Thank you for answer. I know how to serve files for downloading. So no other people can access them escaping authentication. But how to server image file in the view, like in the img tag?

Comment: Use appropriate headers to indicate that the script output is a image. And use the link to this script in img src attribute. `<img src="url to file controller"/>` Check Justinas answer

Comment: @Khaleel This makes sense. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can request that file by PHP script (sorry, I know only Yii1 syntax):

```
?r=resources/get&fileName=filename.png

public function actionGet() {
    $fileName = Yii::app()->request->getParam('fileName');
    $filePath = __DIR__.'/../../../files/'.$fileName;
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $fileName);

    if (file_exists($filePath) && Yii::app()->user->canAccess($fileName)) {
        header('content-type: '.$mime);
        header('content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$fileName.'";');
        readfile($file);
    } else {
        $this->redirect('site/index');
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to prefix action in the function name to use it as an action

Comment: don't forget to make sure that you are really validating filename and path carefully. otherwise this can raise a security issue